# Prove that every ideal of a regular ring is regular

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Prove that every ideal of a regular ring is regular.

Let $R$ be a regular ring with unity, that is to say that each element $x \in R$ can be written as $x=xyx$ for all $y \in R$. And let $K$ be an ideal of $R$; we must see that $K$ is also regular.

Note: an ideal $K$ is a nonempty set in $R$, such that $x-y \in K$, y for all $x,y \in K$ also $xa \in K$ and $ax \in K$ for all $a \in R$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your characterization of regular rings. You write that $R$ is regular if each $x\in R$ can be written as $xyx$ "for all $y\in R$", but  of course you mean to say "for *some* $y\in R$". Incidentally, this is what is called a "Von Neumann regular" ring; there is a different meaning of "regular ring" in commutative algebra.

With this correction in mind, let $x\in K$. To show $K$ is Von Neumann regular, we need to find some $z\in K$ such that $x=xzx$.

Because $R$ is regular, there is some $y\in R$ such that $x=xyx$. This means that in fact $x=(xyx)yx=x(yxy)x$. Because $K$ is a two-sided ideal, and $x\in K$, $yxy\in K$, so letting $z=yxy$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much for the help and the corrections, every day you learn: D

Comment: @holiswis happy it helped! :)

Comment: of course!!!!!!

Comment: I don't know who put that low rating, it will be envious